# reactJS warning propType Invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi together I got this warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `label` of type `object` supplied to `ThemedLink`, expected `string`.
in ThemedLink (created by TooltippedComponent)
```

and this:

```
Warning: Unknown props `primary`, `raised` on <a> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see
```

those probably comes from this:

```
<Button icon='save' type="submit" label={t('user:login.signin')} raised primary/>
<NavLink  to="/signup"  aria-hidden="true"><Button raised>{t('user:login.signup')}</Button></NavLink>
```

is there a way to resolve the warnings?

Comment: What is the output that you expect. What should `label={t('user:login.signin')}` do

Comment: it should be (and it is the label) of the Button. t is from translation react-i18-next

Comment: It's hard to read your snippets of code without some extra information. Could you share code of the components – Button and NavLink? 
Warnings that you try to solve depends on interface of these components.

Comment: Button is from react-toolbox
and NavLink is from react-router

Comment: `Remove these props from the element. For details, see` see what? Could you share whole warning message, please

Comment: @Felix how do you import your components ? You need to import the `Button` like this for instance: `import {Button} from 'react-toolbox/lib/button';`

Comment: the problem is this line `user:login.signin` , what if you use `login.signin`  I don get why you need `user:`

Comment: there its mention: fb.me/react-unknown-prop

Comment: I need user because its in location files user/login/sigin the cascading arrays

Comment: look at the props validation used by `Button` . The warning is being sent from there

Comment: do you have a solution for the problem?

Comment: any hints according this problem?